# Where to look for real url

Tags: c++, qt, youtube

I'm trying to write simple application for downloading videos from youtube.
My code for getting file (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pViMzR_ylXg) looks like:

```
bool FD_core::get_file()
{
    QNetworkRequest request;

    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pViMzR_ylXg"));
    connect(network_access_manager_, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(onRequestCompleted(QNetworkReply *)));
    network_access_manager_->get(request);
    return true;
}


void FD_core::onRequestCompleted(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    QByteArray data_ = reply->readAll();
    cout << data_.constData();
    qDebug() << "size: " << data_.size();
}
```

In the above function data_.constData() produces lots of text, part (very small) of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr" >

<head>
      <script>
var yt = yt || {};yt.timing = yt.timing || {};yt.timing.tick = function(label, opt_time) {var timer = yt.timing['timer'] || {};if(opt_time) {timer[label] = opt_time;}else {timer[label] = new Date().getTime();}yt.timing['timer'] = timer;};yt.timing.info = function(label, value) {var info_args = yt.timing['info_args'] || {};info_args[label] = value;yt.timing['info_args'] = info_args;};yt.timing.info('e', "907050,906359,927900,919320,914021,916611,922401,920704,912806,927201,925706,928001,922403,913546,913556,920201,911116,901451");yt.timing.wff = true;yt.timing.info('pr', "1");yt.timing.info('an', "dclk,aftv,afv");if (document.webkitVisibilityState == 'prerender') {document.addEventListener('webkitvisibilitychange', function() {yt.timing.tick('start');}, false);}yt.timing.tick('start');yt.timing.info('li','0');try {yt.timing['srt'] = window.gtbExternal && window.gtbExternal.pageT() ||window.external && window.external.pageT;} catch(e) {}if (window.chrome && window.chrome.csi) {yt.timing['srt'] = Math.floor(window.chrome.csi().pageT);}if (window.msPerformance && window.msPerformance.timing) {yt.timing['srt'] = window.msPerformance.timing.responseStart - window.msPerformance.timing.navigationStart;}    </script>

<script>var yt = yt || {};yt.preload = {};yt.preload.counter_ = 0;yt.preload.start = function(src) {var img = new Image();var counter = ++yt.preload.counter_;yt.preload[counter] = img;img.onload = img.onerror = function () {delete yt.preload[counter];};img.src = src;img = null;};yt.preload.start("http:\/\/o-o---preferred---sn-xn5ucu-q0ce---v3---lscache7.c.youtube.com\/crossdomain.xml");yt.preload.start("http:\/\/o-o---preferred---sn-xn5ucu-q0ce---v3---lscache7.c.youtube.com\/generate_204?ip=95.83.224.63\u0026upn=A3aUhLYV55M\u0026sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire\u0026fexp=907050%2C906359%2C927900%2C919320%2C914021%2C916611%2C922401%2C920704%2C912806%2C927201%2C925706%2C928001%2C922403%2C913546%2C913556%2C920201%2C911116%2C901451\u0026mt=1354207274\u0026key=yt1\u0026algorithm=throttle-factor\u0026burst=40\u0026ipbits=8\u0026itag=34\u0026sver=3\u0026signature=692E605215EB4D2CA407291CA26E14B844768A89.7A2930CE25FDDFC7C4FF5AA56DD02538B0020267\u0026mv=m\u0026source=youtube\u0026ms=au\u0026gcr=ie\u0026expire=1354228237\u0026factor=1.25\u0026cp=U0hUSVJNVl9IUUNONF9KR1pDOi0tSFhhRzVFRkd6\u0026id=a5588ccd1ff29578");</script><title>Die Antwoord - Fok Julle Naaiers (Mike Tyson&#39;s Words NOT DJ Hi-Teks) - YouTube</title><link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="http://www.youtube.com/opensearch?locale=en_US" title="YouTube Video Search"><link rel="icon" href="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon-vfldLzJxy.ico" type="image/x-icon"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon-vfldLzJxy.ico" type="image/x-icon">   <link rel="icon" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon_32-vflWoMFGx.png" sizes="32x32"><link rel="canonical" href="/watch?v=pViMzR_ylXg"><link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pViMzR_ylXg"><link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pViMzR_ylXg"><link rel="shortlink" href="http://youtu.be/pViMzR_ylXg">    <meta name="title" content="Die Antwoord - Fok Julle Naaiers (Mike Tyson&#39;s Words NOT DJ Hi-Teks)">

    <meta name="description" content="Some of the lyrics of &quot;Die Antwoord&quot; new single &quot;Fok Julle Naaiers&quot; have caused such controversy that Die Antwoord have split with their record label Intersc...">

    <meta name="keywords" content="Die Antwoord, Fok Julle Naaiers, Mike Tyson, DJ Hi-Tek, Faggot">

    <link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DpViMzR_ylXg&amp;format=json" title="Die Antwoord - Fok Julle Naaiers (Mike Tyson&#39;s Words NOT DJ Hi-Teks)">
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DpViMzR_ylXg&amp;format=xml" title="Die Antwoord - Fok Julle Naaiers (Mike Tyson&#39;s Words NOT DJ Hi-Teks)">

      <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pViMzR_ylXg">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Die Antwoord - Fok Julle Naaiers (Mike Tyson&#39;s Words NOT DJ Hi-Teks)">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Some of the lyrics of &quot;Die Antwoord&quot; new single &quot;Fok Julle Naaiers&quot; have caused such controversy that Die Antwoord have split with their record label Intersc...">
    <meta property="og:type" content="video">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/pViMzR_ylXg/mqdefault.jpg">
      <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/pViMzR_ylXg?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
      <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <meta property="og:video:width" content="853">
      <meta property="og:video:height" content="480">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="87741124305">
    <meta name="twitter:card" value="player">
    <meta name="twitter:site" value="@youtube">
      <meta name="twitter:player" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pViMzR_ylXg">
      <meta property="twitter:player:width" content="853">
      <meta property="twitter:player:height" content="480">
```

So my question is, where in this file is the url hidden which will allow me to download the wanted file?

Comment: @wow, one cannot even ask question anymore on stackoverflow. What's wrong with you people?

Comment: "What's wrong with you people" will probably not help your cause or endear us to keep this question open.

Comment: @JohnDibling I really don't see reason for this question to get close votes? What's wrong with this question? If someone asks you a question and you don't know what he is talking about but you do want to help him, do not turn your back (vote to close), but ask him to clarify. That's the normal way to do it. Voting to close without any explanation nor giving chance to clarify is simply ridiculous.

Comment: We don't close questions if we don't know the answer.  We close questions if they are off-topic, poorly asked, show a lack of research on the part of the asker, etc.  I didn't vote to close, but I suspect that those who did may have done so because of "lack of research effort."  If this is possible, it is surely documented in YT's docs.  If it's not possible it's against the TOC.

Comment: @JohnDibling important part of research is asking questions you know.

Comment: Again, I didn't vote to close.

Comment: @JohnDibling Hopefuly my last post will inform some smart ass wankers that voting to close without *any* explanation nor chance for clarification is simply pig ignorant and pig arogant.

Comment: Based on the general attitude and tone of your comments, I really doubt it.

Comment: @JohnDibling it is not me who behaves like ignorant pig. I simply comment on such behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What you are trying to do is probably violation of terms of service of youtube.
2. Also please check [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/).
3. Also there is [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started) available.

Comment: He hasn't mentioned that he has signed a contract with youtube - so where exactly did you get this "terms of service" from?

Comment: @user93353, IANAL, but using some website/internet service is acceptance of it's terms of service. But again, it's just a warning, there is a word "probably" for it.

Comment: @user:  "By using or visiting the YouTube website or any YouTube products, software, data feeds, and services provided to you on, from, or through the YouTube website (collectively the "Service") you signify your agreement to (1) these terms and conditions (the "Terms of Service"),"  [Source](http://www.youtube.com/static?gl=US&template=terms)  Welcome to the Internet.

Comment: @hate-engine I'm trying to write app so I can practice my C++ skills not so I can download videos from youtube. Youtube downloader, RealPlayer etc already do it.

Comment: @hate-engine it looks like youtube API is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @smallB, but your question is "where in this file is the url hidden which will allow me to download the wanted file?" --- if you have some problems with C++, please, edit your question.

Comment: @user93353:  If you don't like the fact that you are subject to YT's ToS when you use their service, then you have 2 options.  1) Don't use it.  2) Get the law changed.

Comment: @hate-engine I have no problem with C++. I have problem with fining info about "real" url to a video file, which is obviously embeded somewhere in the QNetworkReply I got via QNetworkAccessManager object.

Comment: @hate-engine - Which law is it which says that using some website is an acceptance of it's terms of service?

Comment: @user93353:  You signed a contract when you clicked the "I Accept" button.

Comment: @JohnDibling - you don't need a youtube account to view youtube videos - ergo you can view them without clicking on any "I Accept". Run your browser in private mode & go the url in the question - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pViMzR_ylXg - you can view the video without any login.

Comment: Thats true enough. I cant really claim that i know enough about the law in this area to explain how or even if one is legally bound to a tos when downloading videos.  All i know is that to me it seems like you are and, from my perspective, should be.